# Shell script not sending output to file

Tags: shell, time, sh, stdout, stderr

Whenever I run the following command in the terminal, the `stderr` and `stdout` is sent to the `output.txt` file just like I would expect.

```
/usr/bin/time -v ls -al &> output.txt
```

However, whenever I put this command into a shell script, the output is displayed in the terminal and the output of `output.txt` is empty. Here is the equivalent script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/time -v ls -al &> output.txt
exit
```

I run the script using `./script.sh`. Why doesn't this script behave like I would expect? I have tried replacing the command with: `{ /usr/bin/time -v ls -al ; } &> output.txt`, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sh as interpreter for your script, and the operator &> isn't supported by it. Surely you are using bash to test your command, and that is why it works outside the script.

I think that this answer to another question could be of some help:
https://askubuntu.com/a/625230